# Java program keeps crashing

Tags: java

keeps crashing when i run it, its a palindrom tester ( if a word is the same spelt forwards and backwards) and i want it to remove any non word characters and become lower case. Can anyone spot the problem? or give some tips? im trying to avoid using any "try" "for" stuff etc.. just while and if statements for a project. here is my output:

Enter a possible palindrome : 
p.oop
here it is : poop
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:27)

```
  import java.util.*;


public class Driver
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    String str, another = "y";
    int left, right;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (another.equals("y"))
    {
      System.out.println("Enter a possible palindrome : ");
      str = scan.nextLine();
      String palindromToLowerCase = str.toLowerCase();
      String finalPalindrom = palindromToLowerCase.replaceAll("\\W", "");
      left = 0;
      right = str.length() - 1;

System.out.println("here it is : " + finalPalindrom);

        while (finalPalindrom.charAt(left) == finalPalindrom.charAt(right) && left < right)
        {
          str.toLowerCase();
          left++;
          right--;        
      }
      System.out.println();

      if (left < right)
      {

        System.out.println("that string is NOT a palindrom");
      }

      else
      {
        System.out.println("This string IS a palindrom");
      }

    }


  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by crashing? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: My exeption thrown:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at Driver.main(Driver.java:27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
right = str.length() - 1;
```

to:

```
right = finalPalindrom.length() - 1;
```

Comment: oh my goodness how did i miss that.. thank you so much friend!